# TFS Visual Studio - how do you exclude changes by default in pending changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

It seems the default from checking out a file for edit is to have it included in a check in.  I would prefer to have all my changes excluded by default.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no option to disable this default behavior. You need to manually exclude the changes by clicking the **Exclude All** from the **Included Changes**.

However, you can use Git as alternative, which allows you to use `git add` command to add the specified changes pending to commit.

Please check document [Migrate from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Changing version control is not an option as it is a workplace server.  I do use the Exclude All option, but I am specifically looking for a way to have them left out by default.

Comment: I am afraid now there is not a way to change the default setting.